# Upgrade and new software installation fails

Tags: installation, 13.04, upgrade, dpkg

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The output of `uname -a` is:

> Linux balu-System-Product-Name 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please add some more details like, which version your system is running on, what is it that you were trying to install, and any additional detail that can help solve the question.

Comment: Im using ubuntu 13.04 32 bit.The problem is I can't install any software or update the system.I have a working internet.I have installed all the restricted extras.I think  problem occurred because of incomplete installation of Java7.Please help me.

Comment: could you post the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux balu-System-Product-Name 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Projjol I'm unable to install Tor browser bundle http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut3C7MKUhDE&feature=c4-overview&list=UUdhDnTTgEjYspnnBMzyQznw please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a package that was not installed correctly or is broken. You have to remove linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.

I would suggest that you use the following code:
`gksudo nautilus /var/lib/dpkg/info`
Now find **all** files starting with names linux-headers-3.8.0-19 and delete them. Then:

> sudo apt-get -f install
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install linux

Your system should work fine then.

**Solution #2**

An easier way of doing this using the GUI would be to use a tool called Ubuntu Tweak. It's a great tool, that removes old kernel related files. You can install it using the guide given [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/06/ubuntu-tweak-085-released-install-it-in.html).

Inside Ubuntu Tweak you can use the Janitor option to completely clean your system, after which you can run an update.Hope this answers your question.

Comment: wow! great man this did the trick.Thank you very much.Keep the good work going.

Comment: glad it got sorted out!